# Reports no longer run after change from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

Our crystal reports no longer run after changing the back end database from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2014 (both were enterprise). The database was backed-up on 2008 and restored on 2014 using SQL Server Management Studio. The .Net application works fine except for none of the Crystal Reports run. The screen simply flashes and no PDF is generated or delivered. Reports work fine if we change the connection string in the web.config back to the original server and DB. Below is the connection string with SERVERNAME, DBNAME, USER and Password changed to protect the innocent. The only thing that gets changed is the SERVERNAME.

```
<add name="Pubs" 
     connectionString="Data Source=SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;Integrated Security=False;User Id=USER;Password=*********" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

After checking again, I'm now seeing authentication failures in the SQL logs. I'm not completely sure if these are coming from Crystal Reports. The client IP an a completely different IIS web site IP on the same web server that shouldn't be talking to this DB.

```
Login failed for user '******'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: x.x.x.x]
Source Logon
Message
Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
```

**UPDATE #2**

The developer apparently found some issues with the reports lacking a port being specified for connection and is going through the reports resolving the issue.

Thanks for the input.

Comment: First check if the user gets in SQL Server or not. Check the 'SQL Server Logs' if login failed or 'Activity Monitor' see if user already gets in.

Comment: There are no authentication errors in the SQL logs. I show valid connections from the front end in the activity monitor.  Thanks.

Comment: @Wendy - After checking again, I'm seeing auth errors now.  I updated the original post with the information.

Comment: Can you update the password for this user in SQL Server?

Comment: @Wendy - Yes, I did that. No change.  I also change the DB user password completely and updated all of the web.config's just for grins and no change.  I also tried creating a new db_owner user with another password and we get the same results.  I'm also waiting feedback from the developer to verify that ALL the reports in the app are failing (there's hundreds).

Comment: You should be able to see who are in the SQL Server currently. Login to SQL Server right click servername, Activity Monitor. Or new query window, sp_who or sp_who2.

Comment: @Wendy - All connections are done by the same user specified in the connection string. While I'm seeing a few auth failures for that user, the same user is connected successfully many times as shown in the activity monitor.

Answer (score 0):

The developer apparently found some issues with the reports lacking a port being specified for connection when calling the report from code. They are going through the reports and making the updates to resolve the issue.

Developer input follows....

Had to change subreport logon:

```
rpt.SetDatabaseLogon(sConn.UserID, sConn.Password, sConn.DataSource + ",1433", sConn.InitialCatalog);
            foreach (ReportDocument subReport in rpt.Subreports)
            {
                subReport.SetDatabaseLogon(sConn.UserID, sConn.Password, sConn.DataSource + ",1433", sConn.InitialCatalog);
                for (int i = 0; i < subReport.DataSourceConnections.Count; i++)
                {
                    subReport.DataSourceConnections[i].SetConnection(sConn.DataSource + ",1433", sConn.InitialCatalog, sConn.UserID, sConn.Password);
                    subReport.DataSourceConnections[i].IntegratedSecurity = false;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < rpt.DataSourceConnections.Count; i++)
            {
                rpt.DataSourceConnections[i].SetConnection(sConn.DataSource + ",1433", sConn.InitialCatalog, sConn.UserID, sConn.Password);
                rpt.DataSourceConnections[i].IntegratedSecurity = false;
            }
```

To this:

```
foreach (IConnectionInfo conn in rpt.DataSourceConnections)
        {
            conn.SetLogon(sConn.UserID, sConn.Password);
            conn.SetConnection(sConn.DataSource + ",1433", sConn.InitialCatalog, false);
        }

        rpt.SetDatabaseLogon(sConn.UserID, sConn.Password);

        foreach (Table t in rpt.Database.Tables)
        {
            t.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = sConn.UserID;
            t.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = sConn.Password;
        }
```